# AJAX post to asp.net MVC controller method not working

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I have this method in my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(StatusMessage statusMessage, int foreignKey, int statusMessageType)
{
    //Do something
}
```

This is how my StatusMessage model looks like:

```
public abstract class StatusMessage 
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Message
    /// </summary>
    /// [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

    public int UseraccountId { get; set; }
    public virtual Useraccount Useraccount { get; set; }
}
```

And I'd like to send a post via jquery ajax to my controller:

```
function sendForm(message, foreignKey, statusMessageType, target) {
    var statusMessage = {
      Description: "This is a test message"
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: target,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            statusMessage: statusMessage,
            foreignKey: foreignKey,
            statusMessageType: statusMessageType
        }),
        success: ajaxOnSuccess,
        error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
            alert(exception);
        }
    });
}
```

But the POST isn't sent correctly.
Through testing I figured already out that the problem is the StatusMessage class. If I replace it by a string, everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ajax post is not working because **`StatusMessage` is an abstract class** and you (or the controller) cannot create an instance of it. You should either make it a concrete class or derive another class from it.

Comment: This has some technical background.
This is the base class for some concrete status message classes.
To determine which status message I want I'm using statusMessageType.

Hoped this would work somehow.

Comment: As I've suggested, why don't you then create a concrete class of specific type (e.g. FailedStatusMessage, SuccessStatusMessage)?

Comment: I basically wanted to have only 1 method to create a status message (company status message, project status message).

Comment: How much difference does each type of message have? The downside of having one method is that you will introduce over/under posting if other type of your message have less/more fields than the others. You can always have different controller methods and then have a helper (private) method to centralize the logic of processing the input.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.
I made a seperate "view model" class which is concrete and contains only properties for the data I really want to send via the ajax post.
Now it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Why you have defined your class as **abstract**, controller won't be able to create its instance

Define you class as

```
 public class StatusMessage
```

for info http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6118/All-about-abstract-classes

Comment: This has some technical background.
This is the base class for some concrete status message classes.
To determine which status message I want I'm using statusMessageType.

Hoped this would work somehow.

Comment: You should create derived classes as per message type